# How to write a unit test for Interrupt Signal (Ctrl+C) of an HTTP server?

Tags: unit-testing, http, go, interrupt

Given a small HTTP server, how can you write a unit test to make sure the interrupt is dealt with correctly?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func SimpleServer() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:        ":8080",
        BaseContext: func(net.Listener) context.Context { return ctx },
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/ping", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "pong at ", time.Now().String())
    })

    go server.ListenAndServe()

    exitChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 1) // reserve with buffer size 1 so the notifiers aren't blocked
    defer close(exitChannel)
    signal.Notify(exitChannel, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM) // Docker and Kubernetes will signal with syscall.SIGTERM

    <-exitChannel

    fmt.Print("\n")
    fmt.Println("shutting down server...")

    err := server.Shutdown(ctx)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

I'm wondering how to pass in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498371/how-to-send-an-interrupt-signal):

```
exitChannel <- syscall.SIGINT
```

or:

```
syscall.Kill(syscall.Getpid(), syscall.SIGINT)
```

..and then somehow be notified that the server shut down.

Update:

Following Burak's answer below, here's a working solution:

```
func exampleCaller() {
    exitChannel, serverDownChannel := HTTPServer()

    fmt.Println("sending kill signal in...")
    for i := 3; i > 0; i-- {
        fmt.Println(i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
    exitChannel <- syscall.SIGINT
    fmt.Println("kill signal sent")

    <-serverDownChannel
    fmt.Println("server is down!")
}

func HTTPServer() (chan os.Signal, chan struct{}) {
    responseDelay := 1000 // millisecond delay before sending a response message

    ctx := context.Background()
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:        ":8080",
        BaseContext: func(net.Listener) context.Context { return ctx },
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/ping", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(responseDelay) * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Fprint(w, "pong at ", time.Now().String())
    })

    fmt.Println("creating channels...")
    exitChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 1)                    // reserve with buffer size 1 so the notifiers aren't blocked
    serverDownChannel := make(chan struct{})                  // NOTE: we're not passing any data into this channel
    signal.Notify(exitChannel, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM) // Docker and Kubernetes will signal with syscall.SIGTERM

    go func() {
        <-exitChannel // wait for the signal interrupt
        fmt.Print("\n")
        fmt.Println("shutting down server...")
        err := server.Shutdown(ctx)
        fmt.Println(err)
    }()

    go func() {
        server.ListenAndServe() // start the HTTP server
        close(serverDownChannel)
    }()

    return exitChannel, serverDownChannel
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting for a signal and shutting down, you can refactor a bit to shutdown based on a signal:

```
exitChannel := make(chan struct{}) 
serverDown:=make(chan struct{})
go func() {
   <-exitChannel
   server.Shutdown(ctx)
}()
go func() {
  server.ListenAndServe()
  close(serverDown)
}()
return exitChannel, serverDown
```

Then, you can use the `exitChannel` to terminate the server externally, and `serverDown` to detect if the server shutdown. Hook up the signal channel externally, so when you receive the shutdown signal, you can write to the `exitChannel`.

Comment: thank you, Burak! I'm going to edit my question to incorporate your solution soon...